# AWS User Migration Lambda Returns `Incorrect Username or Password` for First Sign In

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

The below Node.js code is for a lambda function triggered in AWS Cognito's User Migration event.

When a user that is not present in our Cognito User Pool attempts to sign in, this lambda creates a new user in our Cognito User Pool with a state of `Confirmed`:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    if (event.triggerSource == "UserMigration_Authentication") {
        // Validate if this user already belongs in our separate DB, and if so, proceed...

        event.response.userAttributes = {
            "email": event.userName,
            "email_verified": "true"
        };

        event.response.finalUserStatus = "CONFIRMED";
        event.response.messageAction = "SUPPRESS";
        context.succeed(event);
    }
};
```

We are trying to port the above code into a Python (3.8) lambda because most of our code is already in Python.

We had to do some workarounds for some issues we encountered (detailed below):

```
def lambda_handler(event, _):
    if event['triggerSource'] == 'UserMigration_Authentication':
        client = boto3.client('cognito-idp',
                              region_name='OUR_REGION_NAME',
                              aws_access_key_id='OUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
                              aws_secret_access_key='OUR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',
                              config=Config(region_name='OUR_REGION_NAME'))

        # Create a new user in our User Pool.
        client.admin_create_user(
            UserPoolId='OUR_USER_POOL_ID',
            Username=event['userName'],
            UserAttributes=[
                {
                    'Name': 'email',
                    'Value': event['userName']
                },
                {
                    'Name': 'email_verified',
                    'Value': 'true'
                }
            ],
            MessageAction='SUPPRESS'
        )

        # Change the user's password to the same value to change their state from `FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD` to `CONFIRMED`.
        client.admin_set_user_password(
            UserPoolId=_USER_POOL_ID,
            Username=event['userName'],
            Password=event['request']['password'],
            Permanent=True
        )

    return event
```

Above, the `admin_create_user` section creates a new user in our User Pool. According to the ***[documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.admin_create_user)***, the `FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD` state cannot be changed from here:

> In either case, the user will be in the FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD state until they sign in and change their password.

As a workaround, we call `admin_set_user_password` to change the user's password to the same value, with `Permanent` set to `True`. This changes the user's state from `FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD` to `CONFIRMED`.

The difference between the two approaches is that, with the Node.js approach, after the user clicks "Sign In" and the lambda finishes executing, they are redirected to a new page without any issues.

Meanwhile, for the Python approach, after the user clicks "Sign In" and the lambda finishes executing, we get an "Incorrect username or password" error despite the credentials matching. Then, without changing credentials, clicking on "Sign In" for the second time and onwards redirects to a new page without any issues.

No exceptions were raised during the Python lambda's execution.

Is there any way to resolve the unnecessary "Incorrect username or password" error for the Python approach?

Comment: Did you find any info on this? We're trying to do it in python too and according to the docs it looks like you shouldn't have to manually call the admin functions to migrate them in. We always get "Invalid Username and Password" no matter what. I suspect yours works the second time because they were manually migrated in your lambda

Comment: @Cfreak Nope, I believe we dropped this usecase and did something else since it was getting too complicated.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Weirdly after futzing with it for a long time yesterday it suddenly started working after we re-saved the settings.